# Expectation value of a function of a random variable with known properties

Tags: probability, expectation

**Disclaimer:** I am not well versed in probability theory, so I apologize off the bat if I'm missing some terminology. I also could have missed another post about this due to my lack of knowledge.

**Setup:** Consider a disk of radius **R**, and a point **p** a fixed distance **d** above the center of the disk. If I take a uniformly distributed sampling of points within the disk, **X**, I am interested in the PDF and expectation value of the angle created between the radial vector to **X**, and from **X** to **p**, let's call the angle $\theta$.
[Image of setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0fkn.jpg)

**So far:** I have found the PDF and expectation value of the radius of **X**
$$ P_r[X]=\frac{2r}{R^2},\, E_r[X]=\frac{2}{3}R $$
Because the map from $r$ to $\theta$ is injective, $\tan(\theta)=d/r$, the probability of getting an angle, $\theta_0$, should be the same as the probability of the distance, $r_0$, associated to it.
$$P_\theta[\Theta] = P_r[X(\theta)]$$
with $\theta \in \Theta$. This then gives
$$P_\theta[\Theta] = \frac{2r(\theta)}{R^2} = \frac{2d}{R^2 \tan(\theta)}$$
Using $r(\theta)=d\tan(\theta)$.
Now, to find the expectation value of $\Theta$, we take
$$E_\theta[\Theta]=\int_0^{\theta_c} \theta P_\theta[\Theta] = \int_0^{\theta_c} \theta\frac{2d}{R^2 \tan(\theta)} d\theta = \frac{2d}{R^2} \int_0^{\theta_c} \frac{\theta}{\tan(\theta)}d\theta$$
Where $\theta_c$ is the lower bound of $\theta$ due to the finite radius of the disk, $\tan(\theta_c)=d/R$. I couldn't figure out how to do this integral, so I turned to WolframAlpha. The given result is a complicated, complex function involving the polyalgorithm function.

I created a Monte Carlo simulation to help validate my results. The results related to $P_r$ agree with my calculations, and the results for the angle agree with what I expected intuitively (i.e. A high probability of a small angle, with a tangent-like decrease towards $\theta = \pi/2$).

[Monte Carlo simulation results with R=d=1 for 10,000 sample points. Bottom-left: Radial distribution of samples. Bottom-right: Angular distribution of samples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgs10.png)

**Issues:**

1. Evaluating to see if $P_\theta[\Theta]$ is valid by integrating from $\theta_c$ to $\pi/2$ and expecting to get 1
   \begin{align}
   \int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \frac{2d}{R^2 \tan(\theta)}d\theta &= \frac{2d}{R^2} \int_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\tan(\theta)} \\
   &= \frac{2d}{R^2} \Big[\log(\sin(\theta))\Big]_{\theta_c}^{\pi/2} \\
   &= \frac{2d}{R^2}\Big[log(1)-\log(\sin(\theta_c))\Big] \\
   &= -\frac{2d}{R^2} \log\Big(\frac{d}{R^2+d^2}\Big)
   \end{align}
   Which does not appear to be 1, meaning $P_\theta$ is not a valid PDF.
2. $E[\Theta]$ seems like it should be a simple, real-valued function, which it isn't.

**Thoughts:** It seems like there should be a way to use the information I know about $P_r$, and $E_r$ to find simple expression for $P_\theta$ and $E_\theta$ given $r(\theta) = d/\tan(\theta)$, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating the density of a function of a random variable, you can't just plug in the inverse function into the density. You forgot to consider the functional determinant, see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Deviation_using_Integral_Substitution).

In this case, the complicated formula is not necessary. Note that for $0 \le x \le R$ we have
$$P(r \le x) = \int_0^x \frac{2r}{R^2} \, dr = \frac{x^2}{R^2}$$

This yields the following CDF for the angle $\theta$:
$$P(\theta \le x) = P(\arctan(\tfrac{d}{r}) \le x) = P(d/\tan(x) \le r) = 1 - \frac{d^2}{\tan^2(x) R^2}$$
for $\arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big) \le x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Note that for $x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$ the CDF has a value of $1$, while it has a value of $0$ for $x < \arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big)$. You can now determine the PDF of $\theta$ by differentiating the CDF.

If you are mainly interested in the moments, you don't need to calculate the PDF. If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, the following formula lets you calculate an arbitrary $p$-th moment for $p > 0$:
$$E[X^p] = E\Big[\int_0^\infty I\{X > x\} px^{p - 1} \, dx\Big] = p\int_0^\infty x^{p - 1} E[I\{X > x\}] \, dx = p \int_0^\infty x^{p - 1} P(X > x) \, dx$$

For example, the expectation of $\theta$ is
$$E[\theta] = \int_0^\infty P(\theta > x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty 1 - P(\theta \le x) \, dx = \int \limits_0^{\arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big)} 1 + \int \limits_{\arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big)}^{\pi/2} \frac{d^2}{R^2 \tan^2(x)} \, dx \\
= \arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big) + \frac{d^2}{R^2} \left(\frac{R}{d} + \arctan\big(\tfrac{d}{R}\big) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
(See [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20d%5E2%2F(R%5E2*tan%5E2(x))%20dx%20from%20arctan(d%2FR)%20to%20pi%2F2)).